# How to group the items in angularJs

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of items coming from service:Here is my list:

```
[
  {
    "itemCode":"BX0987",
    "itemId":"001",
    "date":"2015-12-09T17:03:56.869-06:00",
    "itemPrice":"$3.24"
  },
  {
    "itemCode":"BX0986",
    "itemId":"002",
    "date":"2015-12-07T17:03:56.869-06:00",
    "itemPrice":"$5.00"
  },
  {
    "itemCode":"BX0985",
    "itemId":"003",
    "date":"2015-12-16T17:03:56.869-06:00",
    "itemPrice":"$7.00"
  },
  {
    "itemCode":"BX0984",
    "itemId":"004",
    "date":"2015-12-15T17:03:56.869-06:00",
    "itemPrice":"$7.00"
  }
]
```

I am trying to display in view:

```
Current Week
BX0985 $7.00
BX0984 $7.00

Last Week
BX0987 $3.24
BX0986 $5.00
```

here is my HTML code:

```
<div ng-repeat="itemDate in items = (itemList()| unique:date)">
    <div id="itemDate" class="font">{{dateHeader(itemDate.date)}}</div>   
    <div ng-repeat="item in itemList()">    
        <div ng-show="dateHeader(itemDate.date) === dateHEader(item.date)" id="itemRow">      
            <div id="contents">               
                <div id="itemCode" class="font">{{item.itemCode}}</div>
                 <div id="itemPrice" class="font">{{item.itemPrice}}</div>                    
            </div>           
         </div>      
    </div>
</div>
```

itemList() is the data coming from service. dateHeader() is a method calculates date and return currentWeek, LastWeek,...
but I am getting this output:

```
CurrentWeek
BX0985 $7.00
BX0984 $7.00
CurrentWeek
BX0985 $7.00
BX0984 $7.00
LastWeek
BX0987 $3.24
BX0986 $5.00
LastWeek
BX0987 $3.24
BX0986 $5.00
```

It is repeating for each item. how do I get the items without repeating?

Comment: Show source of messageList

Comment: sorry that is itemList not messageList.

Comment: There is a typo at `dateHEader`. Also, use `ng-if` instead of `ng-show`.

Answer (score 0):

i would simplify this problem.
Firstly, add a property to each obj in the array giving a week number.

e.g. obj.weekNumber = 1

or something like that. It would be calculated each time the code is executed.

THEN ...

in angular do an ng-repeat inside an ng-repeat

iterate over a list of available week numbers first ... e.g. [1,2]

then do an iteration within the iteration that iterates over the object array

hopefully you can take it from there

any questions plz ask

Answer (score 0):

```
function prepareItemsListForView(items) {
    var currentWeek = [], lastWeek = [];
    for (var item in items) {
        var itemString = item.itemCode + " " + item.itemPrice;
        if (isCurrentWeek(item.date)) { // use dateHeader manually 
            currentWeek.push(itemString);
        } else {
            lastWeek.push(itemString);
        }
    }
    var weeks = {};
    // only add non-empty lists
    if (currentWeek.length > 0) weeks["Current Week"] = currentWeek;
    if (lastWeek.length > 0) weeks["Last Week"] = lastWeek;
    return weeks;
}
```

And then in the view you simply do:

```
<div ng-repeat="(weekString, week) in weeks">
    <div class="font">{{weekString}}</div> <!-- don't use id more than once! -->
    <div ng-repeat="itemString in week">{{itemString}}</div>
</div>
```

Logic should not reach the view.